# Max value in intervals in 2D array in python

Tags: python, arrays, intervals

I have data with 2D arrays with two columns.(first column height,second power)

```
arr1 = np.array([[30, 12.1], [30.2,12.5],[33, 12.4], [30.1,12.7],[34, 13.2], [35,13,7],[34, 13.2], [30.05,12.3],[30.05,12.7]])
```

I would like have intervals for height between 32 in 48 with step 0.3. For each interval I would like calculate maximum value for power.

For example:
I have interval for height example [30-30.3]. The maximum power for that interval is 12.7.

In new 2D array I would like save 30.05 for column height(first column) and 12.7 for column power(second column).

Comment: There is a typo in `[35,13,7]`. I guess you meant `[35,13.7]`

Comment: SO is not a coding service, please read [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Please provide what code have you tried and why it did not work. Please provide which sources have you searched with similar issues and why they did not solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np
def maximum(arr, start,end):
    m = -1
    for i in arr:
        if(i[0]<=end and i[0]>=start):
            if(m<i[1]):
                m = i[1]
    return m
arr1 = np.array([[30, 12.1], [30.2,12.5],[33, 12.4], [30.1,12.7],[34, 13.2], [35,13.7],[34, 13.2], [30.05,12.3],[30.05,12.7]])
print(maximum(arr1,30,30.3))
```

I think this will help you in your desired output.